# How to assign all elements but one in ada?

Tags: ada

How to assign all elements but one in ada?

If i have this

```
element_to_ignore : integer := 3;
a : array(1..4) := (5,3,2,6);
b : array(1..a'length-1) := a( all but element_to_ignore );
```

I need this result:
b = (5,3,6)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use slices and array concatenation.

This program demonstrates how to do it, and also fixes some problems in your code (you didn't specify the element types of the arrays, for example):

```
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
procedure Foo is
    Element_To_Ignore : Integer := 3;
    type Array_Of_Integer is array(Positive Range <>) of Integer;
    A : Array_Of_Integer(1..4) := (5,3,2,6);
    B : Array_Of_Integer(1..A'Length-1)
        := A(A'First .. Element_To_Ignore-1) &
           A(Element_To_Ignore+1 .. A'Last);
begin
    for I In B'Range Loop
        Put_Line(Integer'Image(B(I)));
    end loop;
end Foo;
```

You can also omit the bounds on the declarations of `A` and `B` and let them get the bounds from the initialization. It does mean that when `Element_To_Ignore` is 1, `B` will have bounds `2..4` rather than `1..3`. That shouldn't be a problem as long as you consistently refer to `B'First`, `B'Last`, and `B'Range` rather than using hardwired constants. It also mean that setting `Element_To_Ignore` to 0 or 5 results in `B` being set to `(5,3,2,6)`.

I've created a more elaborate demo [here](https://gist.github.com/4278738).

Comment: See also [*4.1.2 Slices*](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-4-1-2.html).

Comment: +1 for completing the allotted task in the declarations, before `begin`!